# javascript jquery save json object in mysql as string

Tags: jquery, mysql, json, object

i would like to save an object in my table.

my code:

```
var person = {firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"};
var ArticleNo = 373737373737;
var objectArticleNo = {};
objectArticleNo['person'] = person;
objectArticleNo['articleNo'] = ArticleNo;

var addArticleNoToDB = function(objectArticleNo) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/__addArticleNo.php",
  data: {my_json_data: JSON.stringify(objectArticleNo)},
  dataType: "text",
  success: function (msg, string, jpXHR) {
    console.log(msg);
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
});
}
```

php:

```
<?php
$item = $_POST['my_json_data'];
$obj = json_decode($item, true);

$person = $obj['person'];
$articleNom = $obj['articleNo'];

$queryArticle = "INSERT INTO articleNo (articleNom, personAsJsonString) VALUES ($articleNom, $person)";

if(mysqli_query($connection, $queryArticle)) {
   echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "nope";
}
```

the object will be saved as 'array'. But my intend is to save the 'person'-object as a string like

```
'{firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"}'
```

Do I have to parse it again or what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is because you use json_decode decode the json string first. And it is an array in PHP. You could try encode the array to json again before you insert it into your table.

```
$person_json = json_encode($obj['person']);
$queryArticle = "INSERT INTO articleNo (articleNom, personAsJsonString) VALUES ({$articleNom}, '{$person_json}')";
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not send the person object as a string itself--

```
var person = JSON.stringify({firstName:"John", lastName:"Doe", age:50, eyeColor:"blue"});
var ArticleNo = 373737373737;
var objectArticleNo = {};
objectArticleNo['person'] = person;
objectArticleNo['articleNo'] = ArticleNo;

var addArticleNoToDB = function(objectArticleNo) {

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "php/__addArticleNo.php",
  data: {my_json_data: JSON.stringify(objectArticleNo)},
  dataType: "text",
  success: function (msg, string, jpXHR) {
    console.log(msg);
  },
  error: function(xhr, desc, err) {
    console.log(xhr);
    console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
  }
});
}
```